# How to write function and pass parameters for a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below jquery snippet is working fine. I want to know how to write it as function which accepts the table1 as a parameter so that I can reuse this function in other section of the code. For e.g. If I have table with id table2 instead of adding new function I should re use the existing one

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#table1").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: Write selector based on that. There is no need to register more functions for a similar events

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to handle use attribute selector in one way

```
  $("[id^=table]").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a different approach and assign a behaviour class, eg:

```
$(".table-with-removable-rows").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

then whenever you want this behaviour, you add that class, eg:

```
<table class="table-with-removable-rows">...
```

that way there's:

- no need to change any code
- it doesn't affect every table, only the ones you set this to
- you don't need to format the id to trigger the behaviour
- the behaviour is clear on the html

Comment: I like this approach

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy, just name your function and use it wherever you want

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  var deleteAction = function() {
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  };
  $("#table1").on('click', '.btnDelete', deleteAction);
  $("#table2").on('click', '.btnDelete', deleteAction);
  $(".btnDelete").on('click', deleteAction);
  // etc etc.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){    
      $("#table1").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
         RemoveRow($(this));
      });

      function RemoveRow(table){
         $(table).closest('tr').remove();
      }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using [**`multiple-selector`**](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```js
 $("#table1,#table2,#table3").on('click', '.btnDelete', function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });
```

- Using [**`Attribute-starts-with`**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```js
$("[id^=table]").on('click', '.btnDelete', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```